# upgrade magento 2.3.0 to 2.4.1 admin not working

Tags: admin, magento-upgrade, magento2.4.1

How can I fix “Refused to load the stylesheet because it violates the following Content” in Magento 2.4.1

[image]

Comment: Looks like Magento added CSP to 2.4 by default: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/security/content-security-policies.html. Look at your Magento/Csp/etc/config.xml and see if you can whitelist the domains that are mentioned in the error reports.

Comment: You can also set CSP to report only mode in etc/config.xml. This will just report what domains violate the CSP